# Unity 5 - Lightmapping looks very different than realtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is probably a noob question, but I am playing with lightmaps in unity and I am finding that with baked lights and the same lighting settings (intensity etc) the scene looks much darker.

This means that for me to test how it will actually look realtime is not a good indicator and baking every time I change a color or increase light intensity would be an extremely time consuming process.

Is this normal? Is there a good workflow for this that someone can share?

I also have the issue of character which needs to have realtime lights. If I increase the light intensity to compensate for the above, the character appears very bright (as it's using realtime).

Hope this makes sense and somebody can help me out!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You need to think that Lightmapping is a pre setup of the scene in the same way you make any prefab or character with their textures and uvmap, the only difference is that you have prerender in the texture the light and shadows to skip realtime light and shadow calculations.

In addition, you can add some realtime lightning effect without modify your lightmapping and some GI to got your desire illumination in all scene including your characters.

Comment: I understand this but either I am doing something wrong or Enlighten have some serious issues. I followed several tutorials and ultimately with a directional light as bake only and a couple of sample assets I get VERY dark results. I can bump the light intensity to like 3x more, but then my non static models (e.g characters) will appear overly bright.

Ultimately the results I get with a bake are extremely inconsistent with realtime. Obviously it's supposed to be different and more realistic but if  it's not predictable and bake takes ages it becomes very hard to manage.

Comment: Can you show me your material of the baked texture surface?

Comment: Hey man,
I am just using material with albedo, 0 smooth and 0 metalic in a standard shader. All models use this setup (e.g house can have wood, wall etc, but all of them are standard shader with albedo only). This is due to the flat color style we want to have in the game.

Comment: It's very slow to help if we can't get all info, is more easy if you add a snapshoot of your material that describe this.... But well, What base color are you using  in your albedo material?